# How to calculate cpu usage of pod in kube state metrics?

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus, kube-state-metrics

I monitor the eks cluster using both the kubernetes api and the kube state metrics remotely using prometheus.
in Kubernetes api we have a metrics **`container_cpu_usage_seconds_total`** which gives the cpu usage of the pod.
is there a similar metrics in kube-state-metrics which can give the cpu usage.
Actually I'm trying to get the cluster cpu usage which is totally different from kubernetes api and kube-state-metrics
following are the calculations.

**`kube-state-metrics:`**

`sum(kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores) / sum(kube_node_status_allocatable_cpu_cores) * 100` - This gives 101%

whereas the kube-state-metrics gives `12%` which looks accurate to me.

**`kubernetes-api:`**

`sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{id="/",kubernetes_io_hostname=~"^$Node$",  job=~"$job$"}[5m])) / sum (machine_cpu_cores{kubernetes_io_hostname=~"^$Node$",  job=~"$job$"}) * 100`

I don't think there's any metric in kube-state-metric which gives cpu usage compared to kubernetes-api

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no (one) specific metric for cpu usage per container in **kube_state_metric.**

The value you got:
 `sum(kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores) / sum(kube_node_status_allocatable_cpu_cores) * 100 = 101`
may be wrong because metrics like **kube_node_status_allocatable_cpu_cores** and **kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores** are marked as **DEPRECATED**.

At the same time, take notice that there is metric like **kube_pod_container_resource_limits_cpu_cores**.
Your container could have set resource limit, that's why probably your result exceed **100 %**. If you have limit set per container check if resource limit is lower than resource request and then your calculation should looks like:
 `[sum(kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores) - sum(kube_pod_container_resource_limits_cpu_cores)]/ sum(kube_node_status_allocatable_cpu_cores) * 100`.

Take a look at every resource metrics in **kube_state_metrics** for container and nodes:
[node_metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/node-metrics.md), [pod_container_metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/pod-metrics.md).